# Mix GP and AP question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I appreciate your good help:

Two consecutive terms of a GP are the 2nd, 4th and 7th terms of an AP respectively. Find the common ratio of the GP.

Comment: How can *two* terms of a GP be *three* terms of an AP?

Comment: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ~ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to assume that you meant that **three** consecutive terms of the geometric progression are the second, fourth, and seventh terms, respectively, of an arithmetic progression.

Let $r$ be the common ratio of the geometric progression. Let $a$ be the first term of the arithmetic progression, and let $d$ be its difference. Finally, let $b$ be the first of the three terms of the geometric progression. Then $b=a+d$, $br=a+3d$, and $br^2=a+6d$. Subtracting the first of these equations from the second, we find that $b(r-1)=2d$. Subtracting the second from the third yields the equation $br(r-1)=3d$.

From $b(r-1)=2d$ we get $r-1=\dfrac{2d}b$. Substituting this into $br(r-1)=3d$, we get

$$br\left(\frac{2d}b\right)=3d\;,$$

which is easily solved for $r$.

Note that I did make a couple of silent assumptions about $b$ and $d$ in these calculations; I’ll leave it to you to work out what they are, but if you have a question, just leave a comment.

Comment: Further to @zackkenyon's comment we need to note that $d=0$ (whence $r=?$) or ... (the sequence $0, 0, 0 \dots$ providing some interesting possibilities as a special case)

Comment: @Mark: *sigh* I thought that I’d leave it to the OP to sort out the obvious restrictions on the calculation.

Comment: Let's hope it is obvious ... I am hugely in awe of Gauss in Disquisitiones, mirrored a bit in Hardy and Wright (whish I found first - both on number theory) where the relentless pursuit of the obvious seems to lead effortlessly to extraordinary insight!

Comment: Much appreciate @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Sylvester: You’re welcome.